# Inherited Class Return Type of Inheriting Class

Tags: java, kotlin

Say I have the following set up where User is a bean with validations.

```
abstract class AbstractBase {
    private val validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().validator
    
    fun validate(): Set<ConstraintViolation<AbstractBase>> {
        return validator.validate(this)
    }

}

class User : AbstractBase {}
```

How can I make `User().validate()` return a `Set<ConstraintViolation<User>>` or typed by whatever the inheriting type of AbstractBase is?

Comment: `AbstractBase<T extends AbstractBase<T>>`

Comment: `AbstractBase<out T : AbstractBase<T>>`, delcare the User class as: `class User : AbstractBase<User>`. Return type will be: `Set<ConstraintViolation<T>>`